# How can asyncs detect that they should not continue when returning?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

While an async is awaited - the state of the application might be changed by the user. How can we handle that? For example - while an async method is editing an image - the user crops the image. This is not only about the async keyword, it's about any 2nd task.

Setting flags seems both impractical and error prone.

So how do we handle this? (Not only the above example, of course.)

Comment: This is the hardest part of asynchronous processing : to define rigorously which actions can be run beside others. I use to set flags and call a UILogic() method that enable / disable UI items before and after an async call.

Comment: @Larry Exactly. I was hoping there is some system to put it all in order.

Comment: Unfortunately all `async/await` examples are fire and forget style (to look short and cool)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, it makes no sense to allow further image editing operations until the background operation (suppose it is an enhancement of some kind) completes. The crop will have to work on the results of the enhancement, because the image data they want to alter does not exist until the background process completes.

So from a user interface point of view, you would absolutely use a flag, however you only need one. If any operation is in progress, do not allow the user to begin another operation. They can get their tools ready, zoom, or whatever, but not alter the image.

Comment: Thanks. But this becomes quite complex quickly - zooming is fine, so can changing the view, etc. - half of the options would be OK and half not. I would have to set a flag for crop, change brightness, paste,... Or imagine a complex application like Visual Studio - some actions interfere with some others, but these same actions do not interfere with others...

Comment: @ispiro, yes, programming is hard.

Comment: OK. Maybe I'm overthinking this and setting flags won't be the mess I'm imagining it to be...

Comment: After posting my comment I saw your second one. +1 for the comment! :) (and the answer)

Comment: You only need one flag: Is a background operation in progress? If so, don't begin another.

Comment: That depends on which operation. Zooming is fine. so is copying and many others. But I get your point - there will only be two types of operations. (Or _should_ be) those that block each other, and the rest.

Comment: Have a matrix that shows your operations in both rows and columns. Then set a True or False mark in the boxes to decide whether the operation in the row can run beside the one in the column. Once this is defined, it should be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 2):

> While an async is awaited - the state of the application might be changed by the user. How can we handle that?

There are a few approaches.

You can prevent the user from initiating another operation while one is in progress. One common approach is to disable certain UI elements so that it's not *possible* to initiate a second one.

You can queue user operations.

You can use [cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx) to (try to) stop any in-progress asynchronous operations.

You can use an "asynchronous tag", which is just a simple value (like `new object()`) that an operation creates and saves, and then double-checks at the end of the operation before applying its results - if the tag has changed, then it knows its result is outdated.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite understand the last one ("asynchronous tag"). What did you mean by that?

Comment: @ispiro: When starting the async op, create a `new object()`, save it to a private field, and pass it to the op. When the op completes, it checks its tag against the one in the private field; if they don't match, then it knows it's out-of-date.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Nice idea.